# How to determine the convergence of this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Define the function $f(z,x)$ :
$$f(z,x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-zn^{k}}\;\;\;\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;z\in\mathbb{C}/[0,\infty)\;,\;\;\;\;n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$$
and let $p(x)$ be the function :
$$p(x)=\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}$$
where $\left \{ x \right \}$ is the fractional part of $x$. I am trying to determine whether the integral :
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}p(x)f(z,x)dx$$
converges or not. My attempt:

Using a formula due to Stieltjes :
$$\log\Gamma(a)=\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log a-a+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p(x)}{x+a}dx\;\;\;\;\; a\in\mathbb{C}/[0,-\infty)$$
and the periodicity of $p(x)$, we have :
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{p(x)}{x+a}dx=\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(a+1)-a-1+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-\log\Gamma(a+1)\;\;\;\;\;a\in\mathbb{C}/[-1,\infty)$$
Thus, our integral reads :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-zn^{k}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1-zn^{k}\right)-1+zn^{k}+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-\log\Gamma\left(1-zn^{k}\right)$$
But there are two problems with this formula: the interchange of the integral and summation signs is not justified, since the integral is not absolutely convergent. The second problem, i don't know how to check whether the resulting series converges or not. Stirling's asymptomatic formula seems to suggest that it does converge. But Wolfram alpha seems to disagree for various values of $z$, except when $z\in [0,-\infty)$. Hence the question.

Comment: An useful observation is that $\int_0^1p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. This allows you to write the integral as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1(f(z,k+x)-a_k)\left(x-\tfrac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$, where you can choose any $a_k$ to make the integral of $|f(z,k+x)-a_k|$ small.